# Mobile Apps - Remember unique device?

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile, server

I am working on a mobile app using the Godot engine, which is partly irrelevant to the question, and I am wondering on what information I can grab from the user's device within the app that is unique to the mobile device they are using?

Ultimately, I want to be able to store this unique ID in a database. If user uninstalls the app and any local data, resets phone, etc etc, and then reinstalls the app and connects to my server - I can see this unique ID and connect it back to the user's relevant information.

I am thinking of possibly storing the device's mac address or static IP address, though I am wondering if there is a better or simpler way to goes about.

Comment: For IOS app you could use `Keychain` to store a specific value. It doesn't get deleted unless the device is reset or cleared by user manually.

Comment: @kathayatnk Keychain, hm, interesting I will keep this in mind. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do this reliably.  At least on Android there has been major work done to make this next to impossible to do across installs for privacy reasons.  You can't get the wifi mac except in certain circumstances, and then they do mac address randomization-  it constantly changes (this is for a wide variety of security reasons).  There is no static IP address, cell networks use dynamic addresses.  There are things like the ANDROID_ID, but those get randomized on install on modern versions-  you don't get a phonewide constant anymore.